# Figuring out an SQL query involving one-to-many table

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Table Users:**

(ID | Name)

(1  | John)

(2  | Steve)

**Table Notifications:**

(UserId | NotifType | NotifValue)

(1  | 0    | 1)

(1  | 1    | 100)

(1  | 1    | 101)

( 2  | 0    | 1 )

( 2  | 1    | 100 )

I want an SQL query that is able to get (using SQL join) users that:

- Scenario 1: Have NotifType=0,NotifValue=1 & NotifType=1,NotifValue=100 => Users: John & Steve
- Scenario 2: Have NotifType=0,NotifValue=1 & NotifType=1,NotifValue=101 => Users: John

Comment: Add script for create table, sample data and exepected result corectly formatted

Comment: And what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Philippe I spent 10 minutes formatting using StackOverflow tables but the formatting will be lost after saving (here's a bug). And I have put sample data & expected results

Comment: @Isolated
LEFT JOIN notifications s ON s.UserId = u.id
     where (s.NotifType = 0 and s.NotifValue = 1) and
     (s.NotifType = 1 and s.NotifValue = 100) 
=> will return 0 records.

If I replace "and" with "or", scenario 2 will return John & Steve

Answer (score 0):

For the first conditions (`NotifType=0,NotifValue=1 & NotifType=1,NotifValue=100`) a query can look like this

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users u
JOIN notifications n ON u.id = n.user_id
WHERE (n.notif_type, n.notif_value) IN ((0, 1), (1, 100))
GROUP BY u.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT n.*) = 2
```

Output

| name |
| --- |
| John |
| Steve |

---

For the second conditions (`NotifType=0,NotifValue=1 & NotifType=1,NotifValue=101`) a query can look like this

```
SELECT u.name
FROM notifications n
JOIN users u ON u.id = n.user_id 
WHERE (n.notif_type, n.notif_value) IN ((0, 1), (1, 101))
GROUP BY u.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT n.*) = 2
```

Output

| name |
| --- |
| John |

---

If you want to combine the results, use the `UNION ALL` operator, if it's assumed that `John` should be listed twice.

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users u
JOIN notifications n ON u.id = n.user_id
WHERE (n.notif_type, n.notif_value) IN ((0, 1), (1, 100))
GROUP BY u.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT n.*) = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT u.name
FROM notifications n
JOIN users u ON u.id = n.user_id 
WHERE (n.notif_type, n.notif_value) IN ((0, 1), (1, 101))
GROUP BY u.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT n.*) = 2
```

Output

| name |
| --- |
| John |
| Steve |
| John |

If you don't need to get `John` twice, use `UNION` operator instead of `UNION ALL`.

---

Note that I used `COUNT(DISTINCT n.*)` in the `HAVING` clauses of all queries to avoid miscounting duplicate rows (and I added one duplicate row in the fiddle to demonstrate this problem). If there can't be duplicate rows, you can just use `COUNT(n.*)`.

*db<>fiddle with all queries [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ccfdf793b776925c7cde3d42e8fe7c2c)*